# htaccess redirect specific subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm would like to setup a htaccess HTTP 301 redirect from `/abc/*` to `http://newdomain.com/xyz/*`.

I'm trying with this rewrite rule, but it is not working as expected:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It redirect `/abc/test` to `http://newdomain.com/xyz/abc/test`. How can I change the rewrite rule to remove the `abc` part from the request uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

to :

```
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/xyz/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Bacuse the `%{REQUEST_URI}` in the first line including `/abc/` so you should seperate it from URI .

your all rules should look like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/xyz/%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So , `%1` represent this `(.*)?` after `/abc/` in `RewriteCond`

You could also summerize this rule like the folwoing :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test